# OpenAM resutful authentication using x509 certificate

Tags: rest, certificate, x509certificate, openam

Does anybody know or have experience on how to do x509 certificate authentication using openAM restful api. Could not find any useful information from official documentation and Google. The last post from a closed openAM [issue track](http://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-134) indicate the newest API might be able to do certificate authentication. However the detail information is still missing from the link. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First be certain to understand what SSL client auth means and how your infrastructure is setup ... where is the SSL endpoint...

Then read

http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#rest-api-auth-json

it tells you about which parameters you have to provide.

Apart from others OpenAM allows for 'service-based' (authentication chain) and 'module-based' auth.

So either you created an auth chain which has cert auth module configured or you use the module directly.

service-based auth: authIndexType -> service,  authIndexValue -> name_of_auth_chain
module-based auth: authIndexType -> module, authIndexValue -> name_of_the_auth_module_instance

Don't forget to look at OpenAM debug logs (debug level set to 'message').

Comment: Bernhard, Thank you for your response. I believe I have everything set up right. However, I always get 405 error indicating "The method specified in the request is not allowed for the resource identified by the request URI". I do not know what could be wrong. Thanks,

Comment: This is because you're using HTTP GET method instead of HTTP POST